# Maximum nullity of a linear transformation given that the nullity of T restricted to a subspace is s.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T: $\mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C^m$ be a linear map and W be a d-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ such that the nullity of $T|_{w}$ is s. Then the nullity of T is at most n-d +s. Is this true or false?

**Observations** So the question leads me to try "decomposing" T into W and $W^c$, the orthogonal complement of W in T. So we know that W has s elements in the basis for the kernel of T. And we also know that $W^c$ has dimension of n-d. So the kernel of T in W^c has at most dimension n-d. Is it okay for me to then say that therefore the statement is true? Or did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement, and your explanation of the proof, are both correct but not completely clear.

- It is not  $T$ which is being decomposed, but rather $\mathbb C^n$ into $W$ and $W^c$.
- If you want to be a little more formal, this is the way  to do it : apply the rank nullity theorem to $T|_W$ to get $\mbox{ran } T|_W + \ker T|_W = d \implies \mbox {ran } T|_W = d-s$.

  Now, $\mbox{ran } T|_W \leq \mbox{ran } T$. Thus, $\mbox{ran } T \geq d-s$, so $\ker T \leq n-d+s$, since the sum of these two must be $n$ by the rank-nullity theorem.
- Note that the inequality cannot be made stronger.  Can you see why?

Comment: Thank you. My interpretation is that the inequality cannot be made stronger, say at Ker(T)<=n-d+s-1 or something, because you can choose the subspace to be the whole space, which means that Nullity(T)=n - n+s=s which would satisfy the original inequality, but not if was made any stronger.

Comment: Correct. If you wanted to be more precise, then I could ask you to do this : for each d,s,n you can find a T so that the inequality is an equality : this is also easy to do.